# TkinterでFrameの切り替えができない

Tags: python, python3, tkinter

Tkinterを使用して、上下キーを押すとCanvas内のFrameを切り替えるプログラムを作成しています。
プログラム自体には問題がないはずですが、なぜかFrameの切り替えが正常に動作しません。
どのように修正すればよいでしょうか。

以下が現在のコードです:

```
import tkinter as tk
#白いフレームを表示
def switch_to_frame2(event):
   frame1.pack_forget()
   canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame2, anchor="nw")

#黒いフレームを表示
def switch_to_frame1(event):
   frame2.pack_forget()
   canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame1, anchor="nw")

root=tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
#フレームを作成
frame1 = tk.Frame(canvas,width=500,height=500,bg="black")
frame2= tk.Frame(canvas,width=500,height=500,bg="white")

#キーイベント
root.bind("<Up>",switch_to_frame2)
root.bind("<Down>",switch_to_frame1)

canvas.pack()

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame1, anchor="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

上記のコードはFrameの切り替えを試みるもので、上キーで白いフレームが、下キーで黒いフレームが表示されるはずです。
しかし、一度切り替えると、以後切り替える事ができなくなります。
問題の修正方法を知りたいです。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 検索して見つかるこんな記事が参考になるかも。[How to switch between two frames in Tkinter?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter), [How to switch between frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57150624/9014308), [Switch between two frames in tkinter in separates files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67992255/9014308), [Switching between frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52789655/9014308), [【Tkinter】複数の画面（フレーム）をボタン操作で切り替えて表示させる【画面遷移(tkraise）】](https://office54.net/python/tkinter/screen-change-tkraise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import tkinter as tk
#白いフレームを表示
def switch_to_frame2(event):
   global canvas, frame1, window_id
   canvas.itemconfig(window_id, window=frame2)

#黒いフレームを表示
def switch_to_frame1(event):
   global canvas, frame2, window_id
   canvas.itemconfig(window_id, window=frame1)

root=tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
#フレームを作成
frame1 = tk.Frame(canvas,width=500,height=500,bg="black")
frame2= tk.Frame(canvas,width=500,height=500,bg="white")

#キーイベント
root.bind("<Up>",switch_to_frame2)
root.bind("<Down>",switch_to_frame1)

canvas.pack()

window_id = canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame1, anchor="nw")

root.mainloop()
```